# How to install SAPI in visual studio for C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, api, sapi

I want to work with SAPI and downloaded the speechsdk51msm.exe. When I try to run it its open through WinZip, and extracted the files. I got msm extension files after extracting.

I don't know how to install any API for VS 2010. I searched but not got any important information.

Please give any link or guidance for installing APIs (SAPI)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are MSI merge files, intended to deploy SAPI on your customer's machine.  Do *not* install them, SAPI 5.1 is obsolete.  I think the current revision level is 5.3, it is deployed as part of Windows and/or by the .NET framework installer.  SAPI is wrapped by the .NET framework since version 3.0

Which is what you should use, System.Speech namespace.

Comment: Oh!! but I think the System.Speech namespace would not come by default. We must need to references the DLLs.

Comment: No, you don't reference the COM components, you add a reference to System.Speech.  Project + Add Reference, .NET tab.

Comment: Great..Can you please tell me how to do that for C++?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to explore speech in .Net, `System.Speech` might be better suited for you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms723627(VS.85).aspx.

As to the SDK, after it unpacks to the directory you specify, you need to run the installer. There is no specific Visual Studio integration. You'd need to P/Invoke to the speech DLLs.